# Checking Status Code without Disrupting Download Processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, download

I'm attempting to download a file via a hidden iframe element.  I'd also like to check the response for an error code when it comes back, for the purposes of displaying an error message if the file preparation fails.  The below code is what I have right now.

```
var srcUrl = "/MyProject/servlet?action=getFile&output=STREAM&asAttachment=Y&param1=userinput1&param2=userinput2

$("#downloadFrame").load(
    srcUrl,
    function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (xhr.status == 204) {
            $("#errorDiv").html(xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
);
```

When the response comes back with the error code, it displays the expected error message.  However, when the file is prepared and return correctly, it doesn't save the byte stream that comes back.  This code will download the file, but it also doesn't check for a status code.

```
 $("#downloadFrame").attr("srcUrl", params);
```

Possibly of interest, this is a jsp page making a request to a java servlet running on Tomcat 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding an action to the success of the download?

```
        let srcUrl = "/MyProject/servlet?action=getFile&output=STREAM&asAttachment=Y&param1=userinput1&param2=userinput2

        $("#downloadFrame").load(
            srcUrl,
            function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (xhr.status == 204) {
                    $("#errorDiv").html(xhr.statusText);
                }
                if (xhr.status == 200 & xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    $("#successDiv").html(xhr.statusText); //xhr.(what you need to save)
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.  I don't think javascript (or jquery) can save files to the local file system.

Comment: No, they can't, I thought you needed to display the status or data that comes as response to the request... Where are you trying to make this work? the server or the user pc?

Comment: The javascript is executing in the browser.  I just can't figure out how to allow the iframe to download and save the byte stream and check the http status code at the same time.